# Can I put step definitions in a folder which is not "steps" with behave?

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I am trying to work with Behave on Python.
I was wondering if there would be a way to put my .py files somewhere else instead of being forced to put them all inside the "steps" folder. My current structure would look like this

```
tests/
    features/
    steps/ #all code inside here, for now
```

What I would like to accomplish is something like

```
tests/
    features/ #with all the .feature files
    login/ #with all the .py files for logging in inside a service
    models/ #with all the .py files that represents a given object
    and so on
```

The only BDD framework that I used before Behave was Cucumber with Java, which allowed to insert the step definitions wherever I wanted to (and the rest was handled by Cucumber itself). 
I am asking this because I would like to have a lot of classes in my project in order to organize my code in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from the behave Documentation (Release 1.2.7.dev0):

> behave works with three types of files:
>
> 1. feature files written by your Business Analyst / Sponsor / whoever with your behaviour scenarios in it, and
> 2. a “steps” directory with Python step implementations for the scenarios.
> 3. optionally some environmental controls (code to run before and after steps, scenarios, features or the whole
>    shooting match).

So a `steps/` directory is required.

To accomplish a workaround similar to what you have in mind, I tried creating a subdirectory in the `/steps` directory: `/steps/deeper/` and inserted my Python file there: `/steps/deeper/testing.py`. After running behave,  I received the "NotImplementedError", meaning the step definitions in `/deeper/testing.py` were not found.

It appears that behave doesn't search recursively through subdirectories of the `steps/` directory for any additional Python files.

As for what you're trying to do, I think it's decent organizational idea, but since it's not doable, you could do this: instead of having *directories* for the Python files in your `tests/` directory, why not have a good naming convention for your Python file and separate the associated functions into their own Python files? That is:

```
tests/
    features/
    steps/
        login_prompt.py # contains all the functions for logging in inside a service
        login_ssh.py # contains all the functions for SSH login
        models_default.py # contains all the functions for the default object
        models_custom.py # contains all the functions for a custom object
        and so on...
```

Of course, at this point, it really doesn't matter if you separate them into different Python files, since behave searches through all the Python files in `steps/` when called, but for organization's sake, it accomplishes the same effect.

Comment: If this helps, please select it as this question's Answer!

Comment: Sadly it did. I wanted to believe that there could have been a workaround for this but it looks like there isn't... Thank you so much @musikreck for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit late but you can do the following:

Have the structure like this:

```
tests/
    features/
        steps/
            login
            main_menu
            all_steps.py
```

In the subfolders in steps you can create your _steps.py file with the implementation and then in the all_steps.py(or how you want to name it) you just need to import them:

```
from tests.steps.login.<feature>_step import *
from tests.steps.main_menu.<feature>_step import *
etc
```

And when you run this it should find the step files. Alternatively you can have the files anywhere in the project as long as you have 1 Steps folder and a file in the file were you import all steps

Comment: While Running Through intellij runner it's getting successfully executed, While running through behave command getting error

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with additional method, smth like this:

```
def import_steps_from_subdirs(dir_path):
    for directory in walk(dir_path):
        current_directory = directory[0] + '/'

        all_modules = [module_info[1] for module_info in iter_modules(path=[current_directory])]

        current_directory = current_directory.replace(Resources.BASE_DIR + '/', '')

        for module in all_modules:
            import_module(current_directory.replace('/', '.') + module)
```

Then call this method in before_all layer

Answer (score 0):

I adopted `Bidonus'` solution as follows, this should be copy/paste-able:

`features/helpers/import_helper.py`

```py
from importlib import import_module
from pkgutil import iter_modules
from os import walk
from pathlib import Path

def import_steps(steps_dir: Path):
    assert steps_dir.exists()

    for (directory, _, _) in walk(steps_dir):
        if "__pycache__" in directory:
            continue

        if directory == str(steps_dir):
            continue

        current_directory = directory + "/"
        print(f"Importing Additional Steps: {current_directory}")

        all_modules = [module_info[1]
                       for module_info in iter_modules(path=[str(current_directory)])]
        current_directory = current_directory.replace(str(steps_dir) + '/', '')

        for module in all_modules:
            module_path = current_directory.replace('/', '.') + module
            import_module(module_path)
```

Then created an `__init__.py` file:

`features/steps/__init__.py`

```py
from features.helpers.import_steps import import_steps
from pathlib import Path

STEPS_DIR_NAME = "steps"
STEPS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
assert STEPS_DIR.name == STEPS_DIR_NAME

import_steps(STEPS_DIR)
```

Now when I run my tests I first have:

```
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/create_model/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/list_operations/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/assertions/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/assertions/list_assertions/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/context_managers/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/type_switchers/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/test_setup/
Importing Additional Steps: /workspaces/XXXXX/features/steps/dao_function_callers/
…
Test Results
…
```